# Chrome doesn't run multithread on .net microservice?

Tags: multithreading, microservices

I built a .net MVC microservice on my local machine and I run a test case to see how it will happen when I visit a service twice at the same time.  At first I tested it on Chrome but the outcome is so weird which confused me whole afternoon until I tried it on IE browser.

The service is simple:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Hello")]
    [HttpPost("Hello")]
    public IActionResult Hello(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return View();
    }
}
```

This method is saying, wait for 5 seconds and return a view, which is just an empty web page.

So if I visit http://localhost:56332/Hello/ (the port number may change on different machine) the controller will execute this method.

If I open 2 chrome tabs and visit it at same time (refresh both tabs in a very short time), what supposed to happen is: **after 5 seconds, both Chrome tabs should load an empty web page (returned by *Hello* method) at same time.**  Because every time when there is a HTTP request the MVC creates a new instance,which is to say that 2 *Hello* method will be created at same time and 5 secs later, they will finish at the same time.  **However, I'm seeing that the 5 secs later the first chrome tab loads an empty web page, another 5 secs the second chrome tab loads the empty web page.**   Which implies the microservice on Chrome is running sequential.

I then tested it on IE browser.  IE tabs loaded the web page at same time, which implies the microservice on IE browser is running multi threaded.

Any ideas on why this happen differently on different web browsers?

Comment: Sounds like a chrome issue, similar to this: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0FVai6btoedw/?hl=en

Comment: I disabled/enabled the automatic tab discarding but the result is still same.  So its not exactly as that bookmark issue but similar.  Thanks.